# Generate a random number of Addresses each with a unique Type-value with Bogus Faker

Tags: c#, .net, faker, bogus

Im using Bogus https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/ for generating testdata.

I have a Person-object that has properties:

- firstName,
- lastName
- addresses (list)

The Address-Object has properties:

- streetAddress,
- zipCode,
- city
- addressType,

AddressType has enums:  { "work", "home", "SPAR" }

I would like to create a random number of addresses in person between 0 and number of values in AddressType which is 3 in this case. Each created address should have a unique AddressType-value.

What I have tried so far:

```
void Main()
{
    var fakePersons = new Faker<Person>(locale)
      .RuleFor(p => p.firstName, f => f.Name.FirstName(f.Person.Gender))
      .RuleFor(p => p.lastName, f => f.Name.LastName(f.Person.Gender))
      .RuleFor(p => p.addresses, (f, p) => GetAddresses(p).Generate(faker.Random.Number(3))) // from 0 to 3
}

private Faker<Address> GetAddresses(Person p)
{
    return new Faker<Address>(locale)
        .RuleFor(a => a.streetAddress, f => f.Address.StreetAddress())
        .RuleFor(a => a.city, f => f.Address.City())
        .RuleFor(a => a.zipCode, f => f.Address.ZipCode())
        .RuleFor(a => a.addressType, f => f.PickRandom<AddressType>())  // <===

}
```

This will create 0 to 3 addresses in person where each address can have any AddressType-value, so this will not rule out duplicates.

How can this be solved to save state of previously used AddressType-values so there will only be unique AddressType-values?

A side note. Instead of having to hard the number of AddressType-values (3) in the call to '''GetAddresses(p).Generate(faker.Random.Number(3))) // from 0 to 3'''

Is it possible to provide an expression that counts the number of AddressType enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really no expert with Bogus, but it seems to me the simplest approach is to pick N address types, and then generate N addresses without types, and finally set the types for each generated address.

```
private static readonly AddressType[] AllAddressTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AddressType))
                                                       .Cast<AddressType>()
                                                       .ToArray();

private ICollection<Address> GetRandomAddresses(Faker faker, Person p)
{
    // Select random number of addresses,
    // and the same number of random address types
    var num = faker.Random.Number(AllAddressTypes.Length);
    var types = faker.PickRandom(AllAddressTypes, num).ToArray();


    // Build the addresses, without type
    var addresses = GetAddresses(p).Generate(num);  

    // Set the address type for each new address
    for(var i = 0; i < addresses.Count; ++i) {
        addresses[i].addressType = types[i];
    }   
    return addresses;
}
```